# What is a "template context" in ASP.NET MVC and does it affect generation of client-side IDs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I was reading Steven Sanderson's [post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) where he had mentioned this concept and makes clever use of it. However, the concept remains vague to me. Reminds me of `INamingContainer` from web forms though. Official documentation doesn't say much about it either (based on what I have been able to trawl). 
Also, what are the general pitfalls and rules of thumb when it comes to the resulting client-side IDs in MVC?

Answer (score 3):

Let's take an example:

```
public class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public C C { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }    
}
```

Now let's suppose that we have a view which is strongly typed to `A`:

```
@model A
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.B)
```

Inside this view we are inside the context of A. Then we render the editor template of B:

```
@model B
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.C)
```

Now even if we are inside the template for B, it remembered that this template was invoked in the context of A. Finally we go to the C template:

```
@model C
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Inside the C template it remembered that this template was invoked in the context of B which itself was invoked in the context of A so it will generate the following name for the textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="B.C.SomeProperty" id="B_C_SomeProperty" />
```

So basically the ASP.NET MVC templates *remember* the context in which they were called.

This also works with collections. For example:

```
public class B
{
    public IEnumerable<C> C { get; set; }
}
```

and then you do:

```
@model B
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.C)
```

and inside the template for C:

```
@model C
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

since the C editor template will be rendered for each element of the collection it will generate:

```
<input type="text" name="B.C[0].SomeProperty" id="B_C0_SomeProperty" />
<input type="text" name="B.C[1].SomeProperty" id="B_C1_SomeProperty" />
<input type="text" name="B.C[2].SomeProperty" id="B_C2_SomeProperty" />
...
```

Comment: Spectacular explanation!! Thanks. Would it be correct to assume that the framework uses `ModelMetadata.ContainerType` property to get the type name prefixes?

Comment: Thanks for this answer Darin. Peraps @Abhinav will mark this answer as "Acceped" soon!